# Entity Framework Core throws a 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' when doing any database query. Can't find the cause

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<conferencing>> GetEventsByDate(DateTime today)
{
    try
    {
        return await _dbContext.conferencings
            .Where(c => c.Date == today && c.Status != "cancelled" && !c.Suppresssignage)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        throw; // Rethrow the exception to propagate it up the call stack.
    }
}
```

GetEventsByDate() is in the repository layer and when not in the try/catch tags will just freeze up and not allow me to step through it.

In the output the error would contain:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation: Warning: No store type was specified for the decimal property 'Target_Rent' on entity type 'Roomdata'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values in 'OnModelCreating' using 'HasColumnType', specify precision and scale using 'HasPrecision', or configure a value converter using 'HasConversion'.

So in my ApplicationDbContext I added these for each property it gave a warning for like so:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Roomdata>()
    .Property(r => r.Target_Rent)
    .HasPrecision(18, 2);
```

However I still get the same problem it just freezes or throws an exception but doesn't I can't figure out why. I think it might have something to do with the models. It doesn't matter what query I give the outcome is exactly the same. I am using an existing database hooked up to entity framework core.

This is the Roomdata model for instance:

```cs
public class Roomdata
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public float? Size { get; set; }
    public double? Rated_Size { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Target_Rent_Basis { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Target_Rent { get; set; }
    public string Tenant { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Ratable_Value { get; set; }
    public string Rates_Property_Reference { get; set; }
    public string Rates_Account_Reference { get; set; }
}
```

In the database target_rent_basis is (money) object type. Could this have something to do with the errors not mapping properly?

I have tried adding a protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){} which did not solve it.

I have tried the simplest query such as `return await _dbContext.conferencings.ToListAsync();` to no avail.

I have tried taking the connection string out of user secrets and hard coding it in the config.

Comment: What you posted is a warning, not an error. Post the actual full exception text.

Comment: `will just freeze up` that can happen if the *database* blocks, typically because another connection has taken update locks on the same rows you're trying to read. This almost always happens due to lack of indexes and careless coding. EF Core is *far less* susceptible to this because it doesn't keep connections open and uses transactions internally only when `SaveChanges` is called to save all changes at once. Problems like this occur when people try to "improve" it with "repositories" and starting long-lived transactions

Comment: If the search fields *aren't* indexed, the database will have to scan all rows to find matches and block if another connection has locked some of those rows for update. That other connection *shouldn't* keep those locks for long though. If it does, it's a bug in that code

Comment: Could you try to add new migration?

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN how would modifying the database help with blocking? It could cause additional problems though.

Comment: `GetEventsByDate() is in the repository layer` what repository layer? EF Core already is a higher-level abstraction than CRUD classes. Does that layer explicitly start transactions with `BeginTransaction`? Or trying to use multithreading to speed up blocked queries? *That's* the culprit then - the application is blocking itself. A DbSet already is a single-entity Repository, a DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work working with *optimistic* concurrency. No explicit transactions are needed which means blocking is reduced dramatically.

Comment: Can you check if you have awaited all the async methods along the way to GetEventsByDate method?   Sometimes when you dont await all async methods that exception will happen.

Comment: @Murat Can OĞUZHAN - Yes I am able to add migrations.

@Pouya Hashemi - I have checked and all methods are async:


`public async Task GetEvents(Events model)
        {
            DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

            IEnumerable<conferencing> conferencings = await _eventsRepository.GetEventsByDate(aDate);
        }`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - it just says "this task was cancelled".

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'Victoria.Rebuild.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\projects\www\victoria\rebuild\Victoria.Rebuild\Victoria.Rebuild\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: Don't describe the exception. Click on `Copy Details` in the exception popup or log the result of `Exception.ToString()` and add them into the question. It's quite possible your application never awaited that method and exited while the query was still running. The query *will* be cancelled during application termination

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - my repository layer is just for returning the results of the database queries so it keeps the logic out of my controller.

Edit: Okay doing your suggestion now, will update

Comment: 'Victoria.Rebuild.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.20\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x9074 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3ca8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: That `just` is the cause of almost all EF Core questions - because EF Core needs no repository. `GetEvents` seems to discard the results of your method. Is `GetEvents` itself awaited? If not, as soon as the action returns, the DbContext will be disposed and any queries cancelled

Comment: @HarryAR1 That's a debug message, not the exception text. If all you have is something shown in the Debug window, it means `GetEvents` itself, or whatever called it,  wasn't awaited

Comment: Yes when I call the method it is awaited. IEnumerable<conferencing> conferencings = await _eventsRepository.GetEventsByDate(aDate); 

I do have a larger error log from copying the details but is too large to post in this comment box

Comment: Here is the pasted error details:
https://pastebin.com/bE4iCRHk

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. As explained to me by ChatGPT:

When instantiating "conferencings" in my DbContext file

```
public virtual DbSet<conferencing> conferencings { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework would look for a table called "conferencings" and not "conferencing".

When the entity name is in singular form (e.g., User, Product), Entity Framework Core assumes that the corresponding table name is the plural form of the entity name (e.g., Users, Products).

Explicit Name: If an entity's name is already in plural form (e.g., conferencings), Entity Framework Core will use that exact name as the table name without any pluralization.

In my case, since the entity name is conferencing, which is already in plural form, Entity Framework Core assumes that the corresponding table name is conferencings based on the explicit name.

To solve it I just changed the name:

```
public virtual DbSet<conferencing> conferencing { get; set; }
```

and to be safe added:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<conferencing>().ToTable("conferencing");

    }
```

Comment: So ChatGPT helped you to solve TaskCanceledException by fixing mapped table name? ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah, that's literally the only change I made to the code since posting the question.